# POSIX thread pthread_setschedparam

Tags: pthreads

Can anyone help me how to change the thread priority or thread policy? I create a sub thread from main thread, when i try to change the thread priority or thread schedpolicy, using `pthread_setschedprio(pthread_self(),2);` and `pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(),SCHED_OTHER,&param);` it is showing error EINVAL invalid argument. please explain the thing for SCHED_OTHER policy?
Here struct sched_param param;

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what your **param** argument contains (which is of  struct sched_param*   type and has **sched_priority** field - and thus you can set policy and priority at once). Most probably it contains not-supported/out of range value - or garbage if you forgot to initialize it with something like that:

```
struct sched_param param;
param.sched_priority = 2;
```

By the way, valid priorities for a given scheduler policy are within the range returned by the **sched_get_priority_max(int policy)** and **sched_get_priority_min(int policy)** - might be worth to check.

**Update**

From [this](http://ccrma.stanford.edu/planetccrma/man/man2/sched_setscheduler.2.html):

> Processes  scheduled with SCHED_OTHER must be assigned the static
>   priority 0, processes
>          scheduled under SCHED_FIFO or SCHED_RR can have a  static  priority  in
>          the  range  1 to 99

Comment: Thank you very much for making an attempt for my query, regarding that for SCHED_OTHER policy the min and max priority, both i am getting as zero.